# Positive Semi Definite Matrix and its inverse B

Tags: linear-algebra

can someone help me out with this problem? I can't even start on working on it as it is beyond the scope of my comprehension on symmetric positive definite matrix.

---

If $A = \begin{pmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12}\\\ A_{21} & A_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $B = \begin{pmatrix}B_{11} & B_{12}\\\ B_{21} & B_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ is the inverse of A and that each $B_{ii}$ and $A_{ii}$ have dimension  $m_{i}  \times  m_{i}$ how do I show that

$$A^{-1}_{11} = B_{11} - B_{12}B^{-1}_{22}B_{21}$$

---

Thank you!

I can't seem to find this problem online most likely due to the matrix format. If you guys know a thread the same as this, please feel free to link it to me.

Comment: Can you do it if the matrices are numbers instead?

Comment: Hint: block-multiply $AB=I$ to get $A_{11} B_{11} + A_{12} B_{21} = I$ and
$A_{11}B_{21} + A_{12} B_{22} = 0$.  Get $A_{12}$ from the second equation and substitute into the first.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: In your title, you say positive semi-definite, but in the question you have positive definite. It can’t be the former, since a positive semi-definite matrix isn’t invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of the inverse: $$AB = I$$ with $I$ the identity matrix.
In all finite dimensions of any bloc matrix:
$$ I_{\alpha \beta} = \sum_{k=1}^{s} a_{\alpha k} b_{k \beta}$$
In particular, with $\alpha = 1$, $\beta = 1$ and $s = 2$ because you have two rows of bloc matrices. Then $1 = A_{11} B_{11} + A_{12} B_{21}$, then if $\alpha = 2$, $0=A_{11}B_{21}+A_{12}B_{22}$.
Substitute $A_{12}$ from the second equation into the first one.

Comment: WOW This is brilliant! Thanks!